# How do I set up two monitors to work with nvidia geforce 750Ti?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, intel

I have NVIDIA Geforce 750Ti installed as my primary graphics card, as I have two VGA monitors I have connected the primary monitor to the graphics card and secondary monitor to the motherboard. So in my graphics settings, the primary monitor is correctly displaying its information whereas in the secondary monitor it doesn't. The resolution for the second monitor doesn't show the option for 1336x768.

Does installing drivers for Intel HD 530 fix this?

If yes, how can I install Intel HD 530 drivers? Or is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: Driver for any Intel Graphics are open-source, automatically selected and installed when you installed the OS. No user action required.

Comment: *"The resolution for the second monitor doesn't show the option for 1336x768."* would never be shown, as it's not a standard size. The resolution choices available are only what the monitor reports that it can do. Intel drivers are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that manually adding resolution of my monitor fixes my problem of not getting the right resolution in the secondary monitor.

I followed the steps in this link which worked out for me.
https://www.tecmint.com/set-display-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu/

1 : list all active monitors.
$ xrandr --listactivemonitors
2 : To add a missing or custom display resolution, you need to calculate the VESA Coordinated Video Timing (CVT) modes for it. You can do this using the cvt utility as follows.

```
$ cvt 1366 768
```

3 : Copy the `Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync`
from the output of the cvt command and use it to create a new mode using the xrandr

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

4 : Then add the new mode to the display.

```
$ xrandr --addmode DP-1-1 "1368x768_60.00"
```

5 :Now open the Displays and set the new resolution.

The above changes are only temporary and work for the current session (they last until you log out or restart the system).

To add the resolution permanently, create a script called external_monitor_resolution.sh in the directory /etc/profile.d/.

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/profile.d/external_monitor_resol.sh
```

Then add the following lines in the file:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1-1 "1368x768_60.00"
```

Save the changes and exit the file.

Comment: [edit] and add the details from the link